# Callback for celery apply_async

Tags: python, celery

I use `celery` in my application to run periodic tasks. Let's see simple example below

```
from myqueue import Queue
@perodic_task(run_every=timedelta(minutes=1))
def process_queue():
    queue = Queue()
    uid, questions = queue.pop()
    if uid is None:
        return

    job = group(do_stuff(q) for q in questions)
    job.apply_async()

def do_stuff(question):
    try:
        ...
    except:
        ...
        raise
```

As you can see in the example above, i use `celery` to run async task, but (since it's a queue) i need to do `queue.fail(uid)` in case of exception in `do_stuff` or `queue.ack(uid)` otherwise. In this situation it would be very clear and usefull to have some callback from my task in both cases - `on_failure` and `on_success`.

I saw some [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html?highlight=success#celery.app.task.Task.on_success), but never seen practices of using callbacks with `apply_async`. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Subclass the Task class and overload the on_success and on_failure functions:

```py
from celery import Task


class CallbackTask(Task):
    def on_success(self, retval, task_id, args, kwargs):
        '''
        retval – The return value of the task.
        task_id – Unique id of the executed task.
        args – Original arguments for the executed task.
        kwargs – Original keyword arguments for the executed task.
        '''
        pass
        
    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        '''
        exc – The exception raised by the task.
        task_id – Unique id of the failed task.
        args – Original arguments for the task that failed.
        kwargs – Original keyword arguments for the task that failed.
        '''
        pass
```

Use:

```py
@celery.task(base=CallbackTask)  # this does the trick
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Comment: How to pass arguments to on_success or on_failure like in args, and kwargs?

Comment: This does not callback in the task dispatcher end.

Comment: So once the celery worker is completed with success, does it call on_success method?

Comment: @sattva_venu yes, make sure to restart your celery process

Answer (score 9):

You can specify success and error callbacks via the link and link_err kwargs when you call apply_async. The celery docs include a clear example: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#linking-callbacks-errbacks