# How to use result callback for celery AsyncTask

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have the following situatuion.

My `client` sends following task to the worker:

```
# client
task = my_task.apply_async((some_params), queue='my_queue')
# task.get()  # This blocks
```

My worker executes the task properly and returns the result.

So retrieving the result with `task.get()` works but it blocks. Now what I'd like to have is a callback that is called when a result (success or failure) is available.

There is a `on_success` function of the [Task](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html?highlight=success#celery.app.task.Task.on_success) class. But that is used in the worker. [Similiar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526606/callback-for-celery-apply-async)

Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: Does the callback use the result? Perhaps a chain or chord would work well for this. http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html

Comment: @sytech yes it does. But does it matter? I can use `task.get()` to retrieve the result right?

Answer (score 5):

You can have callbacks with a task, but it's not the caller or client that can be notified or called back (because celery is out of process), **it will be another celery task that has to be used as the callback**.  [If you would like to use a callback, you can use celery's link or canvassing functionality](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#callbacks).

For a simple callback that uses the result of the initiating task you can do the following:

```
@app.task
def add(m, n):
    return m + n

@app.task
def callback(result):
    print(f'My result was {result}')

def client_caller():
    add.apply_async(args=(2, 2), link=callback.s())
```