# How to pass parameters in on_success() and on_failure() callbacks in celery?

Tags: python, callback, celery, django-celery

```
from  my_celery import app
from delete_duplicate import DeleteDuplicate

import celery


class CallbackTask(celery.Task):
    def on_success(self, retval, task_id, args, kwargs):
        print "Task id: ", task_id
        print "retval ", retval     
        print "Args ", args
        print "kwargs: ", kwargs

    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        print('{0!r} failed: {1!r}'.format(task_id, exc))   



class Ott(object):
    @app.task(base=CallbackTask())  
    def delete_duplicate_ott():
        print "Inside ott.... "
        DeleteDuplicate().delete_duplicate_ott()
    @app.task(base=CallbackTask())
    def delete_duplicate_noti():
        print "Inside noti.... "
        DeleteDuplicate().delete_duplicate_noti()
```

I used [Callback in celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526606/callback-for-celery-apply-async) to implement above callback.

Above code is working perfectly. 
I want to pass parameters in on_success() and on_failure() callbacks in args or kwargs. Args and Kwargs both print None after successful execution of task.

I search on internet, din't find any solution which follow these kind of call back using inheritance(sub class).

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried doing `@app.task(bound=True, base=CallbackTask())`, setting a attribute inside your task `self.on_success_args = ...` then in `CallbackTask.on_success` checking this variables. But well, wouldn't be the best approach

Comment: I figured out celery callback takes arguments itself that we pass in the task function in the args parameter

Comment: @ascii_walker, can you please post the solution to this