# How can I use Celery's apply_async()/delay() as a non-blocking asyncio coroutine inside an asyncio loop?

Tags: python, celery, python-asyncio

All of the questions I've found seem to want to use a coroutine *inside* the celery worker called from a sync parent process. I want to do the exact opposite. I want an *async loop* to be able to use [`celery.app.task.Task.apply_async()`](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async) (or [`delay()`](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.delay)) as a non-blocking coroutine. For context, I'm calling celery tasks from a [discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) loop and I'd like each command to wait for the task to return and keep the [context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) to reply easily. The program flow should look something like this:

```py
@commands.command()
async def some_kind_of_bot_command(ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.reply("your command is processing...")

    # this should NOT block the event loop
    result = await celery_task_module.some_task_ran_in_celery.delay()

    await ctx.reply("here is the result of your command: " + result)
```

In this example, `some_task_ran_in_celery` is a *synchronous/blocking* task ran within a celery worker.

I don't mind using external libraries or a custom function wrapper/something else as long as it has this kind of behavior.

If this isn't possible or is a bad way to do this, please let me know as I'm open to feedback.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the celery is geared towards multi-processing not towards coroutines and async.  The key thing to remember when trying to integrate with asyncio is that calling `delay` or `apply_async` is a "relatively" non-blocking call (each call will kick off the task by placing a message on the celery broker, like redis or rabbitmq).  To that end, you could do a few things here

1. pay the small penalty of the blocking I/O required to place the message on the broker.
2. write your own asyncio way to place the message on the broker
3. write a polling loop that will check the `AsyncResult` for the task call to see if it is ready (checking the AsyncResult will normally use a blocking I/O call to check on the results in the celery result backend).

You will need (1 or 2) and 3.

Comment: it seems to be possible to listen for events by subclassing Task (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13494345/9044183 ) but I'm interested in point 2. Do you know where I would find the blocking I/O calls to replace them? I'm using RabbitMQ for the backend currently but I don't mind switching for ease of modification as long as I don't lose features.

Comment: Just as an FYI--listening for events involves another multi-processing celery task (i.e., celery notifications of task complete should be handled by other celery tasks).  I'll respond back a bit later on how to subclass the relevant tasks for asyncio.